# Threads C# stop executing program, while not using threads keeps the program running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I´m using -first time- threads -with multiparameters- in C#. The problem I Have is:

If I use the functions -I will post it- without the threat, it will follow the natural logic of the program. Nevertheless, I need to use threads for calling multiple instances of the functions, at the same time. But when I use the threads, **the execution of the program stops**, although I know that the thread is calling the function right because **I see it briefly** -it pop outs a Windows Form! and it prints some messages that I put-

I don´t know why, is relatively simple function. I think that it could be something with the *EventArgs* but not sure -I also pass it as a parameter!-.

Lets see the threads and the functions:

```
 //This is the function that I call in the threads
 public void device(object i, object s, object f)
 {
     int j = (int)i;
     EventArgs g = (EventArgs)f;

      //Connect the devices
      BSSDK.BS_SetDeviceID(m_ConnectedDeviceHandle[j],
          m_ConnectedDeviceID[j], m_ConnectedDeviceType[j]);

      UserManagement userTest = new UserManagement();

      userTest.SetDevice(m_ConnectedDeviceHandle[j],
          m_ConnectedDeviceID[j], m_ConnectedDeviceType[j]);

      //Open a windows form and show the interface!
      userTest.Show();
    }


   // The function with the threads
   private void userTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ...

        //This loop if for testing, the actual value will be other.
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {

            //Notice that I´m sending 3 parameters!
            Thread t = new Thread(unused => device(i, sender, e));

            try
            {
                t.Start();
            }
            catch (ThreadStateException f)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + f);  
            }
         }
       }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is going out of scope when the thread ends.  You will need to do something to keep a reference to it alive.

It's also generally a bad idea to interact with controls from different threads.  Trying to access a control from a thread other than the one that created it can cause cross threading exceptions.  You would have to call Invoke or BeginInvoke to marshal the call to the correct thread.

Comment: is wise to put the thread to wait, so it will not finalize? (I know it sounds bad)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your program is trying to do, but that doesn't sound like a good idea.  It would probably be better to make sure that all controls (including your forms) are created on the main thread, and have the controls call out to do their work in other threads instead of trying to create and manage the form from inside a worker thread. If you are going to do that, it might just be better to change your .Show call in to .ShowDialog, as that will stop the thread from ending until the window is dismissed.  I still don't recommend doing that, even if it works.

Comment: well, the ShowDialog worked. I understand your point. I will see if I can change the logic of the program the create the forms in the thread. But I will be a mess. My program connect to **biometric** devices, and I´m trying to connect and execute -take fingerprint- many devices at the same time. That´s why I´m trying to use threads, but the complexity is high at this point :/ **Thanks for your tips!**

Comment: Where in your code is the long running process that you are trying to move to another thread?  Is it the call to BS_SetDeviceID?  Or is it actually invoked by the user from inside the UserManagement form?

Comment: Well, I have 2 forms -are more, but for this particular spot are 2-: In the **first** I connect the devices using the _BS_SetDeviceID_ which is the code I pasted. In the **second** which comes from the _userTest.Show()_ (_.ShowDialog_) I must click a button and activate the **biometric device**. I use the **thread** to call X **userTest.Show()** forms, where X is the number of connected devices. Of course, this is ugly: I must, somehow, connect the **button** for activate the devices in **all those forms**, so I don´t click in that button **per** form. I think I´m doing a big mess over here.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time looking into threads, I reccomend you to stop here and look at something else instead!:) 
First, what you are trying to do here is a perfect candidate for the new Async library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360). Please note that although it is CTP, MS does support configurations using this.

If you really need to use something similar to what threads are offering, you can use the Task Parallel Library. You can look at tasks as being lightweight threads.

The only situation I would use threads today is when I have a long running operation which I need total control over.

Best regards,

Tibi